# attaching events to window.on("load", function(){}) in jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I've written some code that works like a jquery plugin, assigning css to elements based on their height in relation to each other. I am stuck trying to figure out how to make the plugin work without calling/wrapping it in a window.on("load", function(){}) block from OUTSIDE of the function. I should add that everything runs fine if I call it from within an external

```
 $(window).on("load",function(){})
```

block. My two questions are:

1. how many different times can I assign actions to the $(window).on("load", function(){}) event? If I assign something more than once will each subsequent assignment replace the first and should I be adding something like the javascript addEventListener method instead?
2. How do I assign my action to this event from within the

   ```
    (function( $ ) { $.fn.resizeCss = function() {}; })(jQuery);
   ```

   block?

really stumped here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to assign actions to that `$(window).on("load"...` as many times as you want. One of the main benefits of using `.on` is that it gives you the ability to namespace your event handlers, if you so choose.

For example, in:

```
$(window).on("load.loading1", function(){})
```

the `loading1` is the name of that particular instance of the event handler. This is helpful because you can choose to remove handlers based on their names, in addition to their events.

For example:

```
$(window).off("load.loading1")
```

will unbind ONLY the `loading1` event handler, where as

```
$(window).off("load")
```

will unbind ALL of the `load` event handlers.

As for your second question, I apologize for the confusion, but I was mistaken about `(function($)`. It actually means that the code within it is self-executing. In other words, it executes on its own time, automatically and need-not be put into a handler.

I still suggest that you bind it externally, as it is better coding practice and will generally make your plugin more extensible.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments, I can tell you that you *can* make it so that the `$(window).load` doesn't have to be typed by the developers who use your plugin, but it is very bad coding practice. It would make your plugin significantly less extensible, however. Also, if you do this with `$(document).ready`, it would only work if the caller of the plugin is not an element. The reason for this is because the element that it is called on would have to have been found by jQuery, and, in order for it to have been found, the document must have been ready for it to be visible.

What you can do is add the `$(window).load` handler within your plugin, itself. In other words, it would be inside of the function declared with `$.fn....`. You would probably also want to create some feedback so that your developer can tell if the function was called before the window was loaded. However, as previously stated, I highly advise against this. The better thing to do is to make a note in your documentation that the plugin should generally be called from the `$(window).load...` event. That's really something that should be left up to the developers.

Comment: Great answer about adding namespace to the load event! Thank you! Unfortunately binding to the event within that $(document).ready type function doesn't seem to be working. I should add that it's not just within $(document).ready, but also within the context of defining the jquery plugin itself. I'm not sure why it isn't working though.

Comment: So as to give me better context and so that I can better assist you, may I ask why you want to bind it within the `document.ready`? In the meantime, I will look to verify that declaring it within in that manner IS, in fact, valid (which it should be)

Comment: It isn't that I want to bind it within the document ready, it's that I want to write the function so that whomever uses it doesn't have to wrap it in their own $(window).on("load", function(){}) event. It seems like an unnecessary step in this case, and should be added to the function definition itself.

Comment: v. good answer but putting the $(window).on("load".function(){}) within the jquery plugin definition doesn't work. I"m posting a fidde.

Regarding extensibility, I don't see what's wrong with attaching the event, if I do it under a namespace that won't affect any other window.on("load", function(){})  events as discussed earlier.

Comment: I'm talking about extensibility of your plugin, not `$(window).load`. There is a reason why it is considered bad coding practice. Things like this are meant to be left up to the developers - shortcuts, in this case, are not only ill-advised, but also frowned upon.